# L-Systems and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractals

I'm trying to use L-Systems in LaTeX, but the following minimal example exits with an error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdftex]{book} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw [green!50!black, rotate=90]
    [l-system={rule set={F -> FF-[-F+F]+[+F-F]}, axiom=F, order=4, step=2pt, randomize step percent=25, angle=30, randomize angle percent=5}]
    lindenmayer system; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgf@arrows@invertl 
l.8 ...t=25, angle=30, randomize angle percent=5}]
```

---

**UPDATE**: It seems I might be missing something like:

```
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
```

Which, incidentally, results in the following error:

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibrarylindenmayersystems.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
```

---

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your pgf version?  It appears that l-systems library is in the CVS version of pgf, not in the regular 2.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After I updated to a newer TeX installation (TeX-Live 2010 I think), everything worked fine. Tikz is pretty new in the LaTeX world and seems to be changing fairly rapidly.